# Chart swaps and path inversion in bidirectional path tracing

Tags: raytracing, pathtracing, physically-based, global-illumination, monte-carlo

**I've got a hard time to understand how we would implement the following in practice. I'd be great if someone could explain the details for the example below.**

---

Assume we're generating a path ${\rm x}=(\rm x_0,\rm x_1,\rm x_2)$ of length $2$ using the $(s,t)$-strategy in bidirectional path tracing (see picture below). Assume that there is no participating media in the scene and we're using a pinhole camera.

Now assume $s=0$ and $t=3$. Since we're using a pinhole camera, $\rm x_0$ is deterministically  fixed at the eye. A raster point is determined by drawing random numbers $u_1,u_2\in(0,1)$ and mapping them uniformly to the raster space. The raster point determines a ray $r_1=(\rm x_0,\omega_1)$ with origin $\rm x_0$ and direction $\omega_1$. Assume that $r_1$ hits a surface point ${\rm x_1}$. Now another pair of random numbers $u_3,u_4\in(0,1)$ are drawn and mapped to a direction $\omega_2$ by the$^1$ bidirectional scattering distribution function at $\rm x_1$ and thereby giving rise to the next ray $r_2=(\rm x_1,\omega_2)$. $r_2$ might either hit another point $\rm x_2$ (located on a surface or a light source) or escape the scene. In the last case, we assume that $\rm x_2$ is located on an infinite light.

> In summary, we've used the random numbers $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ to sample $\rm x=(\rm x_0,\rm x_1,\rm x_2)$. Now assume we're switching to the strategy. How can we determine random numbers $v_1,v_2,\ldots$ which would have produced the same path $\rm x$ under the $(1,2)$-strategy?

We should clearly be able to reuse $u_1,u_2$, since $(\rm x_0,\rm x_1)$ is still part of the truncated camera subpath of the $(1,2)$-strategy.

The abstract process is described in Section 6.1 of the paper [Charted Metropolis Light Transport](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.05395.pdf).

[image: (s,t)-strategy]

---

$^1$ It might actually be a composition of multiple BSDFs and $u_3$ is used to select one of it.

**EDIT**: I'm actually trying to implement this in [PBRT](https://www.pbrt.org/). So, if necessary, feel free to assume that each BSDF has only a single component and that this component is of type `(pbrt::BSDF_REFLECTION | pbrt::BSDF_DIFFUSE)`. Thus, you can assume that there is a single Lambertian BSDF at each surface point.